# magento messagesblock messages

Tags: magento

I would like to understand why these two template code snippets give different results:

## 1:

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('localsample/session')->addError('Test'); ?>
<div id="messages_localsample_sample"><?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

displays the message 'Test'

and

## 2:

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('localsample/session')->addError('Test'); ?>
<div id="messages_localsample_sample"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

displays nothing, generating only this in the page source:

```
<div id="messages_localsample_sample"></div>
```

(no specific getMessageBlock or getGroupedHtml has been coded)

The only difference between the two snippets: "Mage::app()->getLayout()" is replaced by "$this".  On the original Magento templates, I find... the "$this" version...

Answer (score 0):

The second example isn't working because your sample module doesn't have a reference to Mage::app()->getLayout().
So you need to call Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml().

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I think it's because we have previously a "Mage::getModel('core/layout')" instead of a "Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')"....
Works as designed... ;-)